# JWPlayer ad positioning

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Is it possible to position a nonlinear static ad in jwplayer? I've googled high and low with no avail as well as read through all the documentation on JWplayer that I could find.

Comment: It only shows up in one place, over the controlbar.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks, Ethan. Any plans to change that in the future? I've already started on a plugin.

Comment: Possibly, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Is this still the case, @emaxsaun?

Comment: I haven't worked at JW Player since 2015. Best to email their support.